# How to do an unpretty json in Java that is already in a pretty format?

Tags: java, json

I've a formatted json.
I want to display it as a one line string in Java.
Any library would help(preferably `org.json`)

Comment: you can sysout(json);

Comment: First question would be: why?

Comment: replace linebreaker would be easy